# Error converting Java.io.File to org.core.resource.IFile?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, java-io, eclipse-pde

I am dynamically creating a File in the workspace and trying to generate a IFile instance of it.

```
            IPath location= Path.fromOSString(file.getAbsolutePath());  
            IFile iFile=ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getFile(location);         
            FileEditorInput input = new FileEditorInput(iFile);
```

but when I try to see if ifile exists or not (using iFile.exists()) it gives false.

I tried using canonical path as well but that also did not help.

Answer (score 2):

Changes to the file system are not automatically detected by the Eclipse workspace, you'll need to tell the workspace to refresh its view of the local file system. You can do this with:

```
iFile.refreshLocal(IResource.DEPTH_ZERO, null);
```

If more than one file has changed you can do the refresh at the folder level changing the depth.

Comment: Sorry, It did not work for me. Are there any other work around.

Comment: I found a work around for it. I used FileStoreEditorInput instead of FileEditorInput and created fileStore using LocalFile. It did the work for me.

Comment: FileStoreEditorInput is really intended for files outside of the workspace. Edits won't be synced to the workspace, which may cause you problems later on.

Comment: Thank you for the extra info but Since that file is temporary created and removed after its use.User is not allowed to edit it.It should not be a issue as of now.But Nick thanks for your support.